# How can we set default value for React RRule Generator in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, recurrence, rrule

I am using **react-admin** and **react-rrule-generator** (https://github.com/Fafruch/react-rrule-generator). Create / Adding records is working fine while using rrule widget. But whenever I try to edit a record, the widget should have its values automatically filled based on the record's values. But the value is always the default one provided by the widget itself. Here is my code:

**main_file.jsx**

```
export const JobCreate = (props) => {
  return (
    <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <CustomRRuleInput name="recurrency" label="Recurrency" />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  )
}
```

***recurrency_field.jsx***

```
export const CustomRRuleInput = (props) => {
  const {
    input: { onChange },
    meta: { touched, error },
  } = useInput(props)

  return (
    <Labeled label={props.label}>
      <RRuleGenerator
        onChange={onChange}
        name={props.name}
      />
    </Labeled>
  )
}
```

If I add `value={props.record.recurrency}` in `RRuleGenerator` component, I can't change values because I kind of fixed / hardcoded its value which is constant even if I try to change them. If this widget had a prop called `defaultValue` then it would have worked out!
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you check closely the documentation's [Inputs/Writing your own input](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html) part you will notice that custom input compoenents using either `useField` or `useInput` hooks still receive the `source` prop which is passed inside the input as part of the hook parameters.

Try this:

Inside main_file.jsx

```
<CustomRRuleInput source="recurrency" label="Recurrency" />
```

Inside recurrency_field.jsx

```
const {
    input: { name, onChange },
    meta: { touched, error },
  } = useInput(props)

  return (
    <Labeled label={props.label}>
      <RRuleGenerator
        onChange={onChange}
        name={name}
      />
    </Labeled>
  )
```

Comment: Now, even "create" doesn't work. Passing `name` instead of `source` in **main_file.jsx** worked successfully. The only problem was that while editing, the **Rrule widget** didn't show the previous value of that record. But using `source` doesn't even let me create or edit the record.

Comment: Sorry I had messed up my code. Create and Edit works. But still I can't get the initialValues while editing the record in the RRule widget!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I did it! I can use this for creation as well as updating records. I also used rrule library for converting rrule to human readable text which gets displayed in TextInput field just below RRule widget. The text dynamically changes when you change data in RRule widget.

**recurrency_field.jsx**

```
import RRuleGenerator from "react-rrule-generator"
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useInput, Labeled, TextInput } from "react-admin"
import { rrulestr } from "rrule"


export const CustomRRuleInput = (props) => {
  const record = props.record
  const {
    input: { onChange },
  } = useInput(props)

  const [state, setState] = useState(record[props.name])

  return (
    <>
      <Labeled label={props.label}>
        <RRuleGenerator
          onChange={(val) => {
            setState(val)
            onChange(val)
          }}
          value={state}
          name={props.name}
        />
      </Labeled>

      <TextInput
        fullWidth
        disabled
        label={"RRule Text"}
        value={state ? rrulestr(state).toText() : ""}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

**main_file.jsx**

```
<CustomRRuleInput name="recurrency" label="Recurrency(r rule)" />
```